# Dispatching causing TypeError 'listener2 is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm simply trying to dispatch an action to the store and am getting this error. I have no idea what listener2 is or why there's a TypeError:

```
listener2 is not a function
TypeError: listener2 is not a function
    at wrappedListener
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.dispatch
    at dispatch
    at App
```

---

This is my only slice:

```
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const PostContainerSlice = createSlice({
  name: "postContainer",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    addPost: (state, action) => {
      state.push(action.payload)
    },
  }
})

export const {addPost} = PostContainerSlice.actions;
export default PostContainerSlice.reducer;
```

---

store.js:

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import PostContainerReducer from './features/post/PostContainerSlice.js';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    postContainer: PostContainerReducer
  }
})
```

---

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import store from './store.js';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App dispatch={store.dispatch} state={store.getState()} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

store.subscribe(root);
```

---

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import PostContainer from './features/post/PostContainer'

function App(props) {
  const {state, dispatch} = props;

  dispatch({
    type: 'postContainer/addPost',
    payload: 'test'
  })
  console.log(state)

 
}

export default App;
```

Console logging the store's state works fine, just dispatching is causing this. When removing 'store.subscribe(root)' from index.js the error doesn't happen, but console logging shows that nothing was dispatched and the store remains unchanged...maybe that has nothing to do with the issue.
Also, when dispatching and logging state from index.js above the App rendering, the store appears to dispatch and log normally... thought this was a clue but has led me nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The "listener" in question here is the listener callback function that `store.subscribe` expects to be passed.

See [subscribe(listener)](https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener)

`ReactDOM.createRoot().render` doesn't return a function.

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App dispatch={store.dispatch} state={store.getState()} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

store.subscribe(root); // root is not a function
```

## Solution

You might be able to get by with creating a function that renders the app that can function as a listener callback as well.

Example:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

const renderApp = () => { 
  root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App dispatch={store.dispatch} state={store.getState()} />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
};

renderApp(); // <-- call once to initially render app

store.subscribe(renderApp); // <-- pass as listener to rerender with state changes
```

***Note:** This **is not** how we use Redux in React though!*

You should import and wrap the `App` component in the `react-redux` `Provider` component to provide the Redux store context to the React app.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import store from './store.js';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

The `App` component, and all components in the sub-ReactTree, should import and use the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks from `react-redux` to dispatch actions to the store, and subscribe to selected state updates.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import './App.css';
import PostContainer from './features/post/PostContainer'

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const postContainer = useSelector(state => state.postContainer);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'postContainer/addPost',
      payload: 'test'
    });
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ postContainer });
  }, [postContainer]);
 
  ...
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for helping me figure this out. This fixed it. I cannot believe though, i've been learning through the Front-end career path with Codecademy and i think they accidentally skipped over an entire section teaching about Provider, useDispatch and useSelector. I have no notes of this and cannot find a section about these things anywhere in the syllabus.
One thing i don't understand though is why without using a useEffect, when using dispatch and logging the state does it result in a never-ending loop?

Comment: @scmgames2 The `dispatch(action)` is a side-effect, which typically results in updating app state, which results in React triggering a component rerender. If you just dispatch the action directly from the component body, this creates a render loop, i.e. *component render* -> *dispatch action* -> *update state* -> *component render*, repeat ad nauseam. The `useEffect` hook only runs on the initial render cycle and when one of its dependencies changes, so the side-effect won't re-run endlessly. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, makes complete sense. Very much appreciate your time to help me. The way you word things is very clear and understandable.